# Windows Forms C# draw whole scrollable panel

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, panel

I have a problem with my scrollable panel in Windows Forms C#.

**My Situation**
I have a Form with a tabControl.
In 1 of the tabs i have a panel that fills the whole tab and is scrollable.
In runtime i fill this panel with about 60 other panels and 6 pictures in each of the added panels. This leads to 1 big panel that i can scroll down.

**My Problem**
Now drawing 1 of these sub panels takes about 0.2 seconds on my bad pc which is fine and reaosnable but i have the problem that it is only drawing the things that are currently visible in the main panel.
Even if i let the main panel load for 1 minute he still only draws the first couple of sub panels and if i scroll down he has to draw the rest.
If i scroll up again everything is smoot, so it looks like it is storing everything that was drawn once.
I would like abehaviour where he basically draws the whole main panel in the beginning and afterwards the scrolling is smooth.

PS: I am not sure if "drawing" is the right word for what the form is doing.
PPS: I know that this code is not perfect, but I am not complaining about performance issues but I just want to understand how this loading works
Some code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            pnEverything.Controls.Clear();
            int yPosition = 20;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 48; i++) {
                Panel panel = new Panel();
                Label label = new Label();

                if (i % 2 != 0) {
                    panel.Location = new Point(10, yPosition);
                }
                else {
                    panel.Location = new Point(this.Size.Width / 2 + 10, yPosition);
                    yPosition += this.Size.Width / 10;
                }
                panel.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width / 2 - 80, ((this.Size.Width / 2 - 80) - 90) / 6 + 40);
                panel.Tag = i;
                panel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;

                label.AutoSize = true;
                label.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                label.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                label.Name = "lbLade" + i;
                label.Location = new Point(panel.Width / 2 - label.Size.Width / 2, panel.Size.Height - 30);
                label.Text = i.ToString();

                panel.Controls.Add(label);

                int xPosition = 30;
                for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
                    MyPictureBox pb = new MyPictureBox();

                    pb.Location = new Point(xPosition, 10);
                    pb.Margin = new Padding(2);
                    pb.Name = "pbLade" + i + "Nummer" + j;
                    pb.Size = new Size((panel.Size.Width - 90) / 6, (panel.Size.Width - 90) / 6);
                    pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    pb.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
                    pb.Position.Lade = i;
                    pb.Position.Nummer = j;

                    xPosition += pb.Size.Width + 10;
                    pb.ImageLocation = @"Bilder\plus.png";
                    pb.Click += new EventHandler(pbAddCar_Click);

                    panel.Controls.Add(pb);
                }
                pnEverything.Controls.Add(panel);
            }
        }
```

Comment: it should be drawing everything on load. can you show us the code?

Comment: PictureBox does nothing to make drawing smooth.  It is entirely up to you to do the work to make it efficient.  The pixel format of the image matters a great deal, only 32bppPArgb is efficient since it is compatible with the video frame buffer format on any modern machine.  Any other format renders ~10 times slower.  And the size of the image matters a great deal, having to rescale the image to fit the picturebox is very expensive and happens over and over again.  Be sure to create your own bitmap with the optimal pixel format and the right size.

Comment: Also you may want to __explain__ why you need to have 360 separate pictureboxes? If you can combine them all into one bitmap everything be be fast. And combining is probably fast as well. But sending many controls to the screen is slow under winforms unless you optimize it perfectly.. And some numbers wrt image sizes would maybe help as well.

Comment: Also are you using 360 **different** images or just one as in the posted code?

Comment: No I am using 360 different images.
I did not post this because of performance issues but because I don't udnersatnd how the loading of this panel works

Answer (score 0):

After Activate the form, Load one Panel and remaining you can load in the Background worker and Invoke.

Comment: Sry but I don't know what you want to tell me.
What panel do you mean that i should load?
At the beginning there are always 5 of the small panels visible in the scrollable big panel